# Proof suggestion for "The chromatic number of a $k$-degenerate graph is inferior or equal to $k + 1$"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring

I have developed a proof by induction but I don't feel confident in its validity:

Base case ($n = 1$) If $G$ only contains one vertex, then its degree is $0$, then $k = 0$ and G is $1$-colorable. This is true since only one colour is required.

Inductive hypothesis: If $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ is also true.

Induction step: Assume $G$ is a $k$-degenerate graph of $n + 1$ vertices. Then, $G$ constains at least one vertex $v$ where $deg(v) \le k$.  If we remove this vertex, we are left with a graph $G - v$ which by definition of degeneracy, is still $k$-degenerate. Therefore, by our assumption $P(n)$, $G - v$ is ($k + 1$)-colourable. Now, we add $v$ back to the graph $G - v$. Since $deg(v) \le k$, $v$ has as at most $k$ neighbours, this leaves one more colour to use.
Thus we have proved by induction that a $k$-degenerate graph is ($k + 1$)-colorable.

Comment: I've added the `solution-verification` tag to the question.

Comment: This solution looks correct to me. Is there any part of your proof you're not completely sure of, or that you think may be incorrect?

Comment: To be completely honest, the inductive step just seems too easy. But if you're saying it's correct I will take your word for it. Thank you !

Comment: The induction step is easy because the definition of $k$-degenerate is designed for this very induction step :)